# $.cookie gives error

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have this message:

> TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new p.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'cookie'

after I have used this code:

```
$.cookie('login', returnedData.login); 
$.cookie('password',returnedData.password);  
alert($.cookie('login'));
```

I have included jQuery and all it's function works fine.

Some help with this please..

Comment: Have you included cookie plugin?\

Comment: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.cookie` is not part of jQuery lib. Include [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) on your page and everything must work.